# Trouble with pySerial deployment

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a custom python script that depends on `MinimalModbus` and the `pySerial` library. I am trying to deploy it to a router which runs a python interpreter.

`MinimalModbus` is just a single .py file which is trivial to deploy. However, the `pySerial` library appears to be much more robust. It looks like several python files that work together to "automatically select the appropriate backend".

Does one have to "install" `pySerial` in order to use it? Or is there some way to extract just the pertinent files/dependencies for a given OS?

I don't know what all is performed when you run pySerial's setup.py (e.g. files copied?). I don't know if it will work for this particular type of deployment. I was hoping to just include specific files.

Any help will be appreciated.

We are using Python version 2.6.

**Update:**

I basically took the "installed" files from the /site-packages/serial folder on my development box and uploaded them to the device. This got me a bit further; however, I am now getting the following error:

[image]

Line ~273 of serialposix.py , it's calling:

```
self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY|os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

Why would it not be able to find the `os.open` routine?

**Update 2**:

Further simplifying the problem, my script now consists of something as simple as the following, and it still fails with the same error:

```
import os
serfd = os.open("/com/0", os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

Under [Python Standard Modules with Digi-Specific behavior](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Digi_Python_Programmer%27s_Guide#Python_Standard_Modules_with_Digi-Specific_Behavior), they make the following comment about the os module:

*Use of the os module in Digi devices is currently very limited. The primary purpose in exposing it is to allow access to the serial ports, which are presented as nodes in the file system. Serial ports are available as files with the path in the form /com/0 with the zero replaced by the zero-based index of the serial port to control.*

In addition, both of their sample applications use the os.open routine for serial communication.

I would have expected to maybe see an error such as: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/com/0', but this is not the case. Python can't even locate the os.open routine.

**Would you expect the os.py file to have a `def open(...)` routine defined?**

Comment: Can't you use something to do the install for you, like [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/)?

Comment: I'm still learning about this device (router) and python, but I don't think the router has a "traditional" python installation. All of the main python libraries and files are contained in an archive named python.zip. I believe at runtime, another python component named zipimport "extracts" these files, runs the program, and cleans them up. Have you ever heard of anything like that? I've added the pySerial files in their own zip file that behaves similarly. But something is still not quite right...

Comment: `serialposix` should not be used on Windows IIRC, please see https://github.com/makerbot/pyserial/tree/master/serial pyserial's `__init__` imports actual functions from posix or windows or java implementation. common functions are in serialutil. Do you have native win32 python or some DIY build? perhaps mingw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening a support case with the manufacturer of this router, it turns out that the `os.open` function is not supported on this device. However, the device does support `io.open` which I believe is similar. More importantly, I learned that the manufacturer provides their own "pyserial" implementation specifically designed to work on the device's operating system. Internally, it looks like they've switched out the calls to use `io.open` equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

having had a look through the source files, i believe that it is entirely python based, and when it installs it copies the files across to the site-packages folder.

having said that it appears that you would need several of the source files in order for it to work, and if you were simply copying them across you may need to modify their imports to ensure they work properly.

eg for linux you would need the serialposix.py file and the serialutil.py

you may need more than just this, but i have only had a quick look through.

but at the top of serialposix.py there is a line:

```
from serial.serialutil import *
```

this would need to be changed to:

```
from serialutil import *
```

and there may be other such changes to make.

but ultimately this seems to use ctypes to do the hard work talking to the underlying OS, so you should be able to make it work.

UPDATE:
to explain why it is calling os.open, on most platforms serial ports are treated almost like files, in tthat the return a "file like" handle, the idea behind pyserial is to abstract operating system level differences away to create a single easy to interface to these, but ultimately it is still treated as a file like handle by the OS.

just for clarification could you let us know what version of pyserial you are using? as the line number you quoted and what i'm looking at don't match.

i suspect the main reason you are having difficulty is the zip nature of the python deployment you are using, but i do find it hard to believe that OS is not included in it, have you checked the OS python file in the ZIP or is it a compiled python file?

UPDATE 2:
haveing looked at the documentation for the distro you are using i would suggest you have a read through the following:
[Python Standard Modules with Digi-Specific Behavior](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Digi_Python_Programmer%27s_Guide#Python_Standard_Modules_with_Digi-Specific_Behavior)

where is states that some funtionality is limited on these devices, it also gives a method by which you can test if it is supported by telnet/SSH into the device and trying it on the python command line.

also, while it is anot as neat and easy to use as the pyserial module, i suggest you give this a read too:
[Digi Serial Port Access](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Connect_Port_Serial_Port_Access)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. See Update section in the original question. Hopefully, you can provide some additional guidance.

Comment: As it turns out, I'm using pySerial version 2.5. I honestly thought I had downloaded 2.7. I will switch to the latest code, but I don't think that's the issue here. The os python file in the ZIP archive is in fact compiled python code - it has a .pyc extension. Can compiled code run alongside non-compiled? I'm extremely new to python development :)

Comment: on a normal python distribution when you import a normal python file, it compiles it first, and you end up with a compiled and a plain text file next to each other, as yours is in a zip distribution i don't know how/if that would work, out of curiosity where did you get your python dist so i can have a read up on it?

Comment: The device was preloaded with the python distribution ZIP archive from the manufacturer. All of the files in the ZIP are compiled python. There are no normal python files. This documentation is somewhat dated - it's actually using Python 2.6. http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Digi_Python_Programmer%27s_Guide#Purpose_of_this_Guide

Comment: FYI, the device is a Digi Transport WR 41

Comment: i've had a look through and found a couple of things i think you should look at, they are in my amended answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the update. I checked out the two articles you mentioned. I am further researching configuration options for the serial port on the device itself. Maybe there is something there. Both of their samples under Python Standard Modules with Digi-Specific Behavior use os.open for serial communications.

Comment: thats ok, there was some things in the second article i linked to about configuring the serial ports as there is some digi specific method of retaining the settings, meaning that configuration wouldn't be needed in the script, unless of course you needed to be able to set it.